# Android ObservableScrollView endless adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) in my application, using fragments with viewpager recycleview, this is working fine for now. i want to implement Endless adapter for this scrollview.

He is my mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks{
......

mPagerAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        // Padding for ViewPager must be set outside the ViewPager itself
        // because with padding, EdgeEffect of ViewPager become strange.
        final int tabHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tab_height);
        findViewById(R.id.pager_wrapper).setPadding(0, getActionBarSize() + tabHeight, 0, 0);

        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_indicator, android.R.id.text1);
        slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mInterceptionLayout = (TouchInterceptionFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mInterceptionLayout.setScrollInterceptionListener(mInterceptionListener);
.......
}

private TouchInterceptionFrameLayout.TouchInterceptionListener mInterceptionListener = new TouchInterceptionFrameLayout.TouchInterceptionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, boolean moving, float diffX, float diffY) {
            if (!mScrolled && mSlop < Math.abs(diffX) && Math.abs(diffY) < Math.abs(diffX)) {
                // Horizontal scroll is maybe handled by ViewPager
                return false;
            }

            Scrollable scrollable = getCurrentScrollable();
            if (scrollable == null) {
                mScrolled = false;
                return false;
            }

            // If interceptionLayout can move, it should intercept.
            // And once it begins to move, horizontal scroll shouldn't work any longer.
            int toolbarHeight = mToolbarView.getHeight();
            int translationY = (int) ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout);
            boolean scrollingUp = 0 < diffY;
            boolean scrollingDown = diffY < 0;
            if (scrollingUp) {
                if (translationY < 0) {
                    mScrolled = true;
                    mLastScrollState = ScrollState.UP;
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (scrollingDown) {
                if (-toolbarHeight < translationY) {
                    mScrolled = true;
                    mLastScrollState = ScrollState.DOWN;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            mScrolled = false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoveMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev, float diffX, float diffY) {
            float translationY = ScrollUtils.getFloat(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout) + diffY, -mToolbarView.getHeight(), 0);
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mInterceptionLayout, translationY);
            if (translationY < 0) {
                DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mInterceptionLayout.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = (int) (-translationY + getScreenHeight());
                mInterceptionLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            mScrolled = false;
            adjustToolbar(mLastScrollState);
        }
    };
```

where should i maintain the scroll end and request for loading more items. can anyone please help me.